# how to add onchange event on dropdown in angular ?

Tags: javascript, angular

could you please tell me how to add onchange event on dropdown  in angular ? I made a simple demo in which initially I fetch `bank names` and show in `drop down` . Now I want to add `on change event` on that dropdown .In other words I want to which `bank` user select . Using that  `bank` name I want to get `state names`

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-batt5c

```
<select class='select-option' 
        (ngModelChange)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
    <option class='option' 
    *ngFor='let option of dropDownData' 
    [value]="option.seo_val">{{option.text_val}}</option>
</select>

onOptionsSelected(){
  console.log('===');
  // send selected value
  this.seletedValue.emit('');
}
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use (change) event instead of (ngModelChange).

```
<select class='select-option'
    #mySelect
    (change)='onOptionsSelected(mySelect.value)'>
   <option class='option' 
   *ngFor='let option of dropDownData' 
   [value]="option.seo_val">{{option.text_val}}</option>
</select>
```

In typescript file:

```
onOptionsSelected(value:string){
     console.log("the selected value is " + value);
}
```

Comment: how to get value of selected item..I am able to get value using event.target.value

Comment: Yes @user5711656 this is even a cleaner way. There is no need to create a template reference in such case.

Comment: Using Angular 12 and this still worked well.

Comment: On miner mistake that I picked up was adding the (change) event lister on the option instead of the element ie                                                                                        
<option (change) = 'expression'> does not work                                                                                     <select (change)= 'expression'> works fine

Comment: this gave me a hint. I used `formControlName` as I was already using reactive forms. Came here after enabling `strictTemplate`

Comment: @user5711656 if you want to use ```event.target.value``` you have to change the code in the template: ```value="{option.seo_val}"```.

Answer (score 26):

try this.

```
<select class='select-option' [(ngModel)]="selected"
     (change)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
   <option class='option'  *ngFor='let option of dropDownData' 
   [value]="option.seo_val">{{option.text_val}}</option>
</select>

public onOptionsSelected(event) {
   const value = event.target.value;
   this.selected = value;
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: What type is `event` in the handler function?

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe Its of type Event