# Angular 8: unable to get the selected value in select box

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic array and I want to create select box based on this array and also want to selected the value which is defined in the array.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "player settings": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "labelName": "subtitle font size",
          "labelValue": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "lbl": "small"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "lbl": "medium"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "lbl": "large"
            }
          ],
          "dataType": "DD",
          "selectedData": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the `HTML` file, I have the following code:

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let item of responseRaw | keyvalue; let i = index">
    <!-- <td>&nbsp;</td> -->
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let item2 of item.value | keyvalue; let j = index">
            <td> {{item2.key}}
             <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let item3 of item2.value; let j = index">
                    <td class="p-4">
                     {{item3.labelName}}
                    </td>

                    <td *ngIf="item3.dataType == 'DD'">
                      <select name="{{item3.id}}" [(ngModel)]="item3.id">
                        <option *ngFor="let lblSelect of item3.labelValue" [ngValue]="lblSelect.id" [selected]="lblSelect.id == item3.selectedData">
                          {{lblSelect.lbl}}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I see the options are displaying but I can't see the option is selected.
In here, the `selectedData` is 2, so it should selected the option as "medium".

Need your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49715369/7201091 take a look on this answer

Comment: @Klodianshaba Can you please add your answer based on my question?

Comment: @Klodianshaba Please note, I do not want to change options. I want to selected the option based on "selectedData".

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwgnqb

Comment: @AdritaSharma https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhg97q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following:

- In the json data, have selectedData as number instead of string, `"selectedData": 2`
- Bind `selectedData` in  `ngModel` instead of `id`, `[(ngModel)]="item3.selectedData"`

Example:

```
<select name="{{item3.id}}" [(ngModel)]="item3.selectedData">
      <option *ngFor="let lblSelect of item3.labelValue" [ngValue]="lblSelect.id" [selected]="lblSelect.id == item3.selectedData">
            {{lblSelect.lbl}}
      </option>
</select>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sralmg?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Change Listener on your select tag, this way if a different value is selected it sends the value to a method.

So In your case you can add the change listener (I also added value to the option in case NgValue wouldn't work:

```
<select  name="{{item3.id}}" [(ngModel)]="item3.id" (change)="filterData($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let lblSelect of item3.labelValue" [ngValue]="lblSelect.id" [selected]="lblSelect.id == item3.selectedData" value={{lblSelect.id}}>
        {{lblSelect.lbl}}
    </option>
</select>
```

So when a change occur you can catch in your method and filter the list like it should.

Which could be something like this:

```
filterData(value){
    //depending on how you want to filter the data out
    this.data.filter(item=>item.whatever == value);
}
```

Comment: change will works when I change the option value. But i want to select the option by default, based on the "selectedData".

Comment: Try to add `value={{lblSelect.id}}` on the option tag that atleast should do it as your selected property is okay. If the value doesn't work try to look if your selected property has the right data to check with, perhaps the data is never equal and is that why it can't select it or if more then 1 item is being selected.

Answer (score 0):

set selectedData property in ngModel and option's id as value in option like below:

```
<select class='select-option' [(ngModel)]="selectedData 
  (change)='onChangeSelected($event)'>
  <option class='option'  *ngFor='let option of labelValue' 
     [value]="option.id">{{option.lbl}}
  </option>
</select>
```

add a method to handle the changes:

```
public onChangeSelected(event) {
  this.selectedData = event.target.value;
}
```